# JQuery .load() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load the content of a webpage in a div. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When the this item is clicked, the webpage should be loaded inside the content id:

```
<ul><li><a id="menu_top" href='testing.html'><span>My account</span></a></li></ul>
<div id="content"> </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#menu_top").click(function() {
  var href = $ (this).attr('href');
  alert(href);
  $("#content").load(href);
  return false;
});
```

testing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
</head>

<body>
SUCCESS!
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work. I have checked it multiple times but could not find the issue.

Comment: did you wrapped the code in dom ready event??

Comment: What's not working? Errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors, the web-page is not loaded inside content.

Comment: I notice you are using a `div` element in the same context as an `li`! Since `li` elements must be within either an `ol` or a `ul`, and since `div` elements do not belong directly within either of these parent elements I believe you are using invalid HTML. Your browser may be behaving strangely in response to this.

Comment: I think he just simplified the document for us. Open the Console, switch to the network, reload the document, then click the link and check that the document is in fact loading when you click it. If it, check the response, then inspect the <div#content> to see if it has the same as the response.

Comment: The code posted here works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/25hxc9av/ Make sure you've wrapped it in an `onload` handler as the answer below says, and that the `testing.html` page (which should be located within `current/testing.html` is handling the request appropriately.

Comment: Are you running this code on a webserver or locally from your filesystem?

Comment: locally from my filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Milind Anantwar is correct - must have the $(document).ready wrap your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#menu_top").click(function() {
    var href = $ (this).attr('href');
    alert(href);
    $("#content").load(href);
    return false;
  });

});
```

I also tested whether or not the UL or OL tags affected it as @psicopoo mentioned, but it didn't seem to in Chrome.  *ALSO, make sure that "testing.html" is a valid page to load.

*As noted on http://api.jquery.com/load/:  "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol."

Comment: my code is wrapped with dom ready event, I did not include it here

Comment: okay - what about your link (testing.html)... Is that a valid link included in your project?  Personally I've had links to .html that didn't work because it was a .htm page (I'm still a rookie :)). And are you at least getting the alert with the 'href'?

Comment: Yeah deebs, I do get the alert and the link is valid as well.

Comment: What about your other menu click events? or CSS?  something else must be interfering because it's working fine for everyone here.  Hope you can figure it out!

Comment: Many thanks for your replies Debs. I do not have any CSS linked to my html file. I've just followed a tutorial on youtube on the .load() function which is not working for me.

Comment: That doesn't work because it's a different domain.  See same origin policy (as noted above): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: This is probably the issue with my code... JS thinks that both html files are from different domains. Is there another way to load a web-page into div?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59745/discussion-between-deebs-and-user3371414).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're encountering an issue with the page you're trying to load.  I copied your code exactly and it works in Fiddle, see if this works for you, if so, it's probably your page:

```
 testing.html
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fb4j6y6d/

Comment: when I remove the JS code and click on 'My Account' it redirects me to testing.html

Comment: what does the content look like on the testing page? do you have that code as well?

Comment: Added as requested, mate

Comment: I know it works on JSFiddle, but the code is exactly the same on my machine and the content of testing.html is not loaded inside my div. The link is valid, I have made several tests on it.

Comment: Interesting, it could be because you're running locally, and not on a web server, though I just ran it locally as well and it worked fine.  Also make sure to allow scripts to run local, as by default that is disabled in IE.